# Vectorize DataFrame's operation using only previous rows data for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, vectorization

Is there a way to vectorize pandas' DataFrame row operations to calculate using only previous row data without using python-level iteration?

I'm trying to calculate quantiles for a given distribution on each row, but I want to avoid data leakage.

So, for each row, I want to calculate the quantiles for the `sequence[:current_row]`.

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':np.random.random(10)})

qtls = pd.DataFrame({'q1':[],
                     'q2':[],
                     'q3':[],
                     'q4':[],
                     'q5':[],
                     'q6':[],
                     'q7':[],
                     'q8':[],
                     'q9':[]})
for i in range(1,len(test_df)+1):
    qtls = pd.concat([qtls, pd.DataFrame({k:[v] for k,v in zip(['q'+str(j) for j in range(1, 10)], np.quantile(test_df['column_1'].iloc[:i], np.arange(0.1,1.0,0.1)))})])
qtls = qtls.reset_index(drop=True)

test_df = pd.concat([test_df, qtls], axis=1)

test_df
```

So this is the brute-force for loop implementation.

And this is the expected result:

| index | column_1 | q1 | q2 | q3 | q4 | q5 | q6 | q7 | q8 | q9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.374540 | 0.374540 | 0.374540 | 0.374540 | 0.374540 | 0.374540 | 0.374540 | 0.374540 | 0.374540 | 0.374540 |
| 1 | 0.950714 | 0.432158 | 0.489775 | 0.547392 | 0.605010 | 0.662627 | 0.720245 | 0.777862 | 0.835479 | 0.893097 |
| 2 | 0.731994 | 0.446031 | 0.517522 | 0.589012 | 0.660503 | 0.731994 | 0.775738 | 0.819482 | 0.863226 | 0.906970 |
| 3 | 0.598658 | 0.441776 | 0.509011 | 0.576247 | 0.625326 | 0.665326 | 0.705327 | 0.753866 | 0.819482 | 0.885098 |
| 4 | 0.156019 | 0.243427 | 0.330836 | 0.419364 | 0.509011 | 0.598658 | 0.651993 | 0.705327 | 0.775738 | 0.863226 |
| 5 | 0.155995 | 0.156007 | 0.156019 | 0.265279 | 0.374540 | 0.486599 | 0.598658 | 0.665326 | 0.731994 | 0.841354 |
| 6 | 0.058084 | 0.116830 | 0.155999 | 0.156014 | 0.243427 | 0.374540 | 0.509011 | 0.625326 | 0.705327 | 0.819482 |
| 7 | 0.866176 | 0.126621 | 0.156004 | 0.177871 | 0.330836 | 0.486599 | 0.625326 | 0.718660 | 0.812503 | 0.891538 |
| 8 | 0.601115 | 0.136412 | 0.156009 | 0.243427 | 0.419364 | 0.598658 | 0.600624 | 0.679642 | 0.785667 | 0.883084 |
| 9 | 0.708073 | 0.146203 | 0.156014 | 0.308984 | 0.509011 | 0.599887 | 0.643898 | 0.715249 | 0.758830 | 0.874630 |

How can I do it efficiently?

Wouldn't it be easy if there were a `df['some_column'] = df['another_column'].cumquantile()`?

Comment: Sure, but this data is for example only. Not the real deal (the real data is not stochastic).
I'm really interested on how to vectorize it.

Comment: Of the methods listed in [quantile()](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.quantile.html), which one suits your application? You'll need to pick one before vectorisation

Comment: Fixed the seed, thanks!

the 'single' method from quantile() would be the most suitable.

Comment: I'm confused? `single` isn't one of the nine supported methods.

Comment: Sorry, confused pandas.DataFrame.quantile for numpy.quantile. I'm analyzing the nine methods right now.

Comment: So we aren't talking about Pandas, here - and really, this is not a Pandas question at all; this is a Numpy question. Nothing in your data suggest that an actual dataframe is appropriate, and vectorisation is going to drop down to Numpy anyway. You yourself called the Numpy `quantile()` method and not the Pandas version.

Comment: I'll assume that you're still going to want `'linear'` as that's what your current code uses implicitly.

Comment: Got it! the linear offsets the calculation using alpha, beta = (1,1). That's exactly it, so I would consider the previous data, excluding the current value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can really vectorize this, but you could simplify your code to:

```
np.random.seed(0)
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'column_1':np.random.random(10)})

q = test_df['column_1'].expanding().quantile

out = test_df.join(pd.DataFrame({f'q{i}': q(x) for i, x in
                                 enumerate(np.arange(0.1,1.0,0.1), start=1)}))
```

which should nevertheless be faster since this is no longer running `concat` in a loop.

Output:

```
   column_1        q1        q2        q3        q4        q5        q6        q7        q8        q9
0  0.548814  0.548814  0.548814  0.548814  0.548814  0.548814  0.548814  0.548814  0.548814  0.548814
1  0.715189  0.565451  0.582089  0.598726  0.615364  0.632001  0.648639  0.665277  0.681914  0.698552
2  0.602763  0.559603  0.570393  0.581183  0.591973  0.602763  0.625249  0.647734  0.670219  0.692704
3  0.544883  0.546062  0.547241  0.548420  0.559603  0.575788  0.591973  0.614006  0.647734  0.681462
4  0.423655  0.472146  0.520638  0.545669  0.547241  0.548814  0.570393  0.591973  0.625249  0.670219
5  0.645894  0.484269  0.544883  0.546848  0.548814  0.575788  0.602763  0.624329  0.645894  0.680542
6  0.437587  0.432014  0.459046  0.523424  0.546455  0.548814  0.581183  0.611390  0.637268  0.673612
7  0.891773  0.433407  0.480506  0.545276  0.548027  0.575788  0.611390  0.641581  0.687471  0.768164
8  0.963663  0.434801  0.501965  0.546455  0.559603  0.602763  0.637268  0.687471  0.785823  0.906151
9  0.383442  0.419633  0.434801  0.512694  0.547241  0.575788  0.620016  0.666683  0.750506  0.898962
```

Comment: Worked beautifully!

Reduced execution time from 6m to 1.9s.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The challenge in vectorizing this is, that the slicing of the data frame results in intermediate arrays with varying length. Those cannot simply be represented in Numpy, because Numpy does not support ragged arrays. You can work around this, by introducing a fill value `np.nan` and later use `np.nanquantile` instead:

```py
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(28)
data = np.random.random(10)

# add a fill value at the end
data_pad = np.append(data, np.nan)

# build an index array, which contains cumulative indices and -1 for entries to be ignored.
n = len(data)
idx = np.arange(n, dtype=int)
idx_cum = np.tril(idx) + np.triu(-np.ones((n, n), dtype=int), k=1)

# create a pseudo ragged array
data_cum = data_pad[idx_cum]

# Compute quantiles
quantiles = np.arange(0.1, 1.0, 0.1)
with np.printoptions(precision=3):
    print(np.nanquantile(data_cum, quantiles, axis=1).T)
```

Which prints:

```
[[0.729 0.729 0.729 0.729 0.729 0.729 0.729 0.729 0.729]
 [0.578 0.595 0.612 0.628 0.645 0.662 0.679 0.695 0.712]
 [0.212 0.299 0.387 0.474 0.561 0.595 0.628 0.662 0.695]
 [0.207 0.289 0.37  0.43  0.479 0.529 0.578 0.628 0.679]
 [0.234 0.343 0.43  0.496 0.561 0.628 0.695 0.739 0.76 ]
 [0.261 0.398 0.454 0.511 0.536 0.561 0.645 0.729 0.755]
 [0.16  0.226 0.355 0.443 0.511 0.541 0.595 0.695 0.75 ]
 [0.165 0.269 0.409 0.488 0.536 0.595 0.712 0.76  0.803]
 [0.171 0.312 0.443 0.521 0.561 0.695 0.76  0.81  0.874]
 [0.177 0.355 0.477 0.541 0.645 0.75  0.803 0.874 0.958]]
```

I have not done any benchmarking, it might be more performant. But if performance is sufficient, I would also recommend to use @mozway simplified implementation. It is much easier to explain, then the Numpy with fill values.

I hope this still helps!